# How to append multiple form-controls (bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to connect multiple text inputs with the same layout as connecting text-inputs with appends. However, I am not sure how to do that. As per docs, it is only possible to append a button or text to a text-input:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    
      <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox">
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I would like to connect 2 text-inputs. But when I try, the inputs start stacking instead of beeing displayed next to eachother:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    
      <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox">
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: You have to change the "width" property of class ".input-group .form-control" to "auto". It's currently 100%. That's why the input is taking the entire space.

Comment: Thank you that solved it. Do You want to convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `width` property of class `.input-group .form-control` to `auto`. It's currently 100%. That's why the input is taking the entire space.

Note: This will override the default behaviour, so you may add custom class name and then modify, if you want to avoid default modification.